# Javascript - Transition Hiding/Showing FX

Tags: javascript, transition

im trying to get a transition to make a more smooth show/hide effect. I understand how to use the getID and how to show/hide, now my script works Im not able to add any smooth animation, where would I start for this?

```
function showmorepanel(id) {
var bio = document.getElementById("bio" + id);
var cardimg = document.getElementById("cardimg" + id);
  if (bio.style.display === "none") {
        bio.style.display = "block";
        cardimg.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        bio.style.display = "none";
        cardimg.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find [jQuery animations](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp) helpful.

Comment: Use css transitions via opacity and just toggle your element's class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `css` transition and `JS` to toggle to other class. Something like

```js
function showmorepanel(id) {
var bio = document.getElementById("bio" + id);
var cardimg = document.getElementById("cardimg" + id);

   bio.classList.toggle("hide");
   cardimg.classList.toggle("hide");
   
   
}
```

```css
.show{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showmorepanel(2)">Hit</button>

<p id="bio2" class="show">1- This text will toggle on clicking above  button</p>

<p id="cardimg2" class="hide">2- This text will toggle on clicking above  button</p>
```